# reverting a git reset soft

Tags: git, version-control

my initial graph looked like this:

```
* 73f91fd (HEAD -> master) third change
* 9ced830 second change
* 026632e first change
* 5a12d08 second recipe for guacamole
*   7777ef7 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merged in fork/gitcourse (pull request #2)
```

then, I applied the following command to reset the commit history:

```
git reset --soft 7777ef7
```

but later, I realized that the commit 73f91fd was the correct one and I wanted to revert the history and I typed:

```
git reset 73f91fd
```

in this case, I ended up with the following graph:

```
* 73f91fd (HEAD) third change
* 9ced830 second change
* 026632e first change
* 5a12d08 second recipe for guacamole
*   7777ef7 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merged in fork/gitcourse (pull request #2)
```

`git status` tells me that HEAD is detached which is correct. What I don't know is how I can move the master branch forward to be synchronized with the HEAD.

Any comment is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout` has an option for this : [`-B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt)

```
git checkout -B master 73f91fd
```

will checkout said commit while also setting `master` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
# forcibly set 'master' to your current commit
git branch -f master

# set 'master' as the active branch
git checkout master
```